# Create dictionary with unique elements in list and their collocation

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Id need some help with the following:

- Id like to create a function that when inserted a string, i would get a dictionary with the unique elements in the list as the key, and as values the texts that are before and after it.
  for example with the following string:

Id like to have the following:

Important to note that for example some words a repeated and have different values next to it.

I am trying with the following function:

```
def ffg(txt):
    txt = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',txt).lower().split()
    words = list(set(txt))
    indx = [words.index(i) for i in txt] 
    
    
    for x in range(len(txt)):
        res = txt[x]
```

But as you can see, it doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you past a sequence of words, so split the text into words however you please.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def word_context(l):
    context = defaultdict(set)
    for i, w in enumerate(l):
        if i + 1 < len(l):
            context[w].add(l[i+1])
        if i - 1 >= 0:
            context[w].add(l[i-1])
    return dict(context)
```

Result:

```py
>>> l
['half', 'a', 'league', 'half', 'a', 'league', 'half', 'a', 'league', 'onward', 'all', 'in', 'the', 'valley', 'of', 'death', 'rode', 'the', 'six', 'hundred']
>>> word_context(l)
{'half': {'a', 'league'}, 'a': {'half', 'league'}, 'league': {'half', 'a', 'onward'}, 'onward': {'all', 'league'}, 'all': {'onward', 'in'}, 'in': {'all', 'the'}, 'the': {'six', 'rode', 'in', 'valley'}, 'valley': {'the', 'of'}, 'of': {'death', 'valley'}, 'death': {'rode', 'of'}, 'rode': {'death', 'the'}, 'six': {'the', 'hundred'}, 'hundred': {'six'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
import re

def collocate(txt):
    txt = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', txt).lower().split()

    neighbors={}

    for i in range(len(txt)):
        if txt[i] not in neighbors:
            neighbors[txt[i]]=set()

        if i>0:
            neighbors[txt[i]].add(txt[i-1])

        if i < len(txt) - 1:
            neighbors[txt[i]].add(txt[i+1])

    return neighbors

print(collocate("Half a league, half a league, Half a league onward, All in the valley of Death Rode the six hundred."))
```